# How to check if the characters in the corresponding positions in the second string are repeating in same position like in first string? Educative EXAM

Tags: python, string, algorithm, string-comparison

It's from Educative.io 1st exam in "Learn Python 3 from scratch":

**Detecting String Pattern**

In this coding exercise, you are asked to write the body of a function called detect_pattern that returns true or false depending upon whether two strings have the same pattern of characters. More precisely, two strings have the same pattern if they are of the same length and if two characters in the first string are equal if and only if the characters in the corresponding positions in the second string are also equal.

Below are some examples of patterns that are the same and patterns that differ:

| 1st String | 2nd String | Same Pattern |
| --- | --- | --- |
| “” | “” | True |
| “a” | “a” | True |
| “x” | “y” | True |
| “ab” | “xy” | True |
| “aba” | “xyz” | False |
| “- - -” | “xyz” | False |
| “- - -” | “aaa” | True |
| “xyzxyz” | “toetoe” | True |
| “xyzxyz” | “toetoa” | False |
| “aaabbbcccd” | “eeefffgggz” | True |
| “cbacbacba” | “xyzxyzxyz” | True |
| “abcdefghijk” | “lmnopqrstuv” | True |
| “asasasasas” | “xxxxxyyyyy” | False |
| “ascneencsa” | “aeiouaeiou” | False |
| “aaasssiiii” | “gggdddfffh” | False |

For example, if two strings called s1 and s2 contain the following letters:

s1 = "aba"

s2 = "xyz"

then the call detect_pattern(s1, s2) should return False.

*Note:
The function detect_pattern takes two parameters: the two strings to compare.
You are allowed to create new strings, but otherwise **you are not allowed to construct extra data structures to solve this problem (no list, set, dictionary, etc).**
Keep in mind that the method should return the same value no matter what order the two strings are passed.*

Good Luck!

My code:

```
import unittest
import re   # only needed if we use hint from 6th line

''' HINT:
if we add this to the end of 13th line before ending ":":
 and pattern.match(s1.replace(" ", "")) == pattern.match(s2.replace(" ", "")) and len(set(s1.replace(" ", ""))) == len(set(s2.replace(" ", "")))
it will solve more case's but we can't use set() method.
'''

pattern = re.compile("^([a-z][0-9]+)+$") # only needed if we use hint from 6th line

def detect_pattern(s1, s2):
    if len(s1.replace(" ", "")) == len(s2.replace(" ", "")):
        return True
    else:
        return False

class TestDetectPattern(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_basics(self):
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("", ""), True)
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("a", "a"), True)
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("x", "y"), True)
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("ab", "xy"), True)
        # self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("aba", "xyz"), False) # can be solved with hint from 6th line but in this task we can't use set() method
        # self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("- - -", "xyz"), False) # can be solved with hint from 6th line but in this task we can't use set() method
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("- - -", "aaa"), True)
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("xyzxyz", "toetoe"), True)
        # self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("xyzxyz", "toetoa"), False) # can be solved with hint from 6th line but in this task we can't use set() method
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("aaabbbcccd", "eeefffgggz"), True)
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("cbacbacba", "xyzxyzxyz"), True)
        self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("abcdefghijk", "lmnopqrstuv"), True)
        # self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("asasasasas", "xxxxxyyyyy"), False)
        # self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("ascneencsa", "aeiouaeiou"), False)
        # self.assertEqual(detect_pattern("aaasssiiii", "gggdddfffh"), False) # can be solved with hint from 6th line but in this task we can't use set() method

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Does anyone know how to check if the characters in the corresponding positions in the second string are repeating in same position like in first string? - i think this can solve whole problem without using set() method.

Comment: Not sure regex is the correct tool for this job. Is that a requirement?

Comment: No it's not - i'm a beginner in python and i was just looking for some way to solve that task without using set() - this is requirement, here we shouldn't use set() method

Comment: Is this online somewhere so we could test potential solutions there?

Comment: The examples are wrong: `- - -` and `aaa` are not of same length but defined as `True`, neither `ab` nor `xy` contain 2 equal characters respectively but are defined as `True`.

Comment: @KellyBundy here's link to [Exam](https://www.educative.io/courses/learn-python-3-from-scratch/R1xBQBMxxmw/assessment) - it's last question. With my first code i've got 5/10 tests passed on that question. With solution from Benjamin i've got 10/10.

Comment: @ack i think you're right - i've just copy-paste from educative.io task content. Also with deleted space's between "-" signs every test case is passing successfully, without deleting only second case with "-" sign getting Failed at tests

Comment: @ack "ab" and "xy" do have the same pattern, result `True` is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: There were some problems within the condition of the if-statement but this problem should be resolved now.**

This approach should work. I am not very happy with the variable naming within the loop so feel free to change them. I tried it with all the examples you provided so semantically it should be correct.

```
def detect_pattern(s1: str, s2: str) -> bool:
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    for idx, (let_1, let_2) in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)):
        for let_1_inner, let_2_inner in zip(s1[idx:], s2[idx:]):
            if (let_1_inner == let_1) != (let_2_inner == let_2):
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: @KellyBundy You are right. I am correcting it right now.

Comment: @KellyBundy I should definitely check the difference between my IDE and Stack Overflow more thoroughly.....

Comment: [Similar version](https://tio.run/##dVBBCsMgELznFduTCunB9FIC9tgX9FZKSdRQIais5tB@3moSSgntXpydnZ0d9M/4cPZw9JiS0gMoHbWMd9/FqNHSwFsIEWsIzQwY7E/QOze2FeQyA4y6qBjsxAIbtoxKoY4TWjh3Y9AzOTgEyWuQDRgLL@PzavH@2lkIEBlceXsrTXk/82Khskb9t1iTUclBiCyew9F8s3Rb4c@cK3HBSVeVR2Mj3XwM6XpSA5GSMJbSGw), you can see what I meant with halved check.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah yes, that looks a lot prettier. Thank you! I will also put that in the solution above.

Comment: You guys are amazing! Thanks! Now i need to learn what are enumerate() & zip() methods and how to use "for" loop with more than one iteration variable. Cheers!

Comment: @Deadjim Actually you could also implement it without `zip` or `enumerate`. If you click on Kelly's link, you will see a solution that doesn't use `enumerate`. However, I would still suggest reading into these two concepts/functions because they can be pretty useful sometimes.

Comment: @BenjaminRuck yeah i saw his version too, thanks for that help. Is there any nice written documentation that explains how "for" loop works with more than one iteration variable? You used idx, let_1 and let_2 i never saw such kind of way to use that loop

Comment: @Deadjim You could check [this](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/) article for `zip` and [this one](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) for `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am doing this course at educative.io. At first when I read the question I couldn't understand how to do this program exactly.

In the above solution by @benjamin, he is using functions like zip() and enumerate (). These two functions and data structures are not taught yet in this course. So it is not advisable to go for the above solution.

I wrote a program without these two functions and it became a success.

```
def detect_pattern(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    for i in range (len (s1)):
        let_1 = s1 [i]
        let_2 = s2 [i]
        for j in range ( i, len (s1)):
            let_1_inner = s1 [j]
            let_2_inner = s2 [j]
            if (let_1_inner == let_1) != (let_2_inner == let_2):
                return False
    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey here is a very simple function that can be used for pattern matching:

```
def check_string(str1,str2):

    if(len(str1)!=len(str2)):
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(len(str1)):
            for I in range(i+1,len(str1)):
                if str1[I] == str1[i]:
                    indx1=I
            for J in range(i+1,len(str2)):
                if str2[J] == str2[i]:
                    indx2=J
            if(indx1!=indx2):
                return False
    return True

str1 = "catcatcatdogcat"
str2 = "tietietiefrrtie"
result = check_string(str1, str2)
print(result)
```

explanation 1:the two strings must be of the same length

explanation 2: we can iterate over the length of either of string since its same

explanation 3: we now must check the subsequent letters after first letter in string 1 thats why the range starts from i+1

explanation 4: we now check if the letter appears elsewhere in the string and if yes we store this index in indx1

explanation 5: we do the same for the second string as well

explanation 6: we now check if the indexes are same for both the strings this is to check whether the occurrences of the letters are in the same position, if false return False

explanation 7: we return True in the end after we have traversed the entire string to avoid returning True after first instance

This code has been written in python .I hope this helps :)

**Please note that I have used only strings for solving this problem as required by the question in Educative Course Certification exam.**